# python 3 time.sleep() slows down or speeds up by other programs

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Hi I have a question regarding to the `time.sleep()` function in python 3. What I am trying to do is looping a list of value periodically with the rate of 0.001 second/ point. It works fine with 0.01 or higher rate. But at 0.001 or smaller, the rate is heavily affected by opening or turning off other programs. 
For example, I have a list of 100 points and run with 0.001 second per point. Then it would take approximately 100*0.001 = 0.1 second to finish it. However, when I run the code, it takes way longer about 1 second to finish. Then I turn on Google Chrome and open stack overflow or quora websites, then it runs at the right speed about 0.11 second.
I am wondering if there is any solution to fix this issue or an alternative of `time.sleep()` that won't be affected by the other programs. Here is my code for testing `time.sleep()`.

```
import time
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import threading

my_points = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
            11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
            21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
            31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
            41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
            51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
            61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,
            71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,
            81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,
            91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,]

def execute():
   while True:
      start = timer()
      for i in my_points:
         print (i, flush = True)
         time.sleep(0.001) #Problem is here

      end = timer()
      print ("Total time run per cycle: ", end - start)
      time.sleep(2) #To read the time

execute()
```

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here that requires precise sleeping of exactly a millisecond?

Comment: not exact a millisecond. I can be off a little bit but not as ten times bigger. That's what I'm concerned with.

Comment: Again, what problem are you actually trying to solve with this approach? Perhaps there's a better way to do it in general.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question earlier. I'm sending a list of points through Serial port to the Arduino to create a waveform using firmate firmware. Therefore, the faster the rate between points, the nicer the waveform looks.

Comment: If faster is better, why have any delay?

Comment: Faster is better so I can determine the highest frequency I can go with different amount of points, which can be 100 or 1000 depending on the input. Then having delay will have me control the frequency of the cycle regardless of the number of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual entry for [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

> time.sleep(secs)
>
> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.
>
> Changed in version 3.5: The function now sleeps at least secs even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler raises an exception (see PEP 475 for the rationale).

makes it pretty clear that the actual sleep time will only approximate the requested time.  I have separately read that the resolution on Windows is 1/60 s, though I don't know if that is still true.

You can do much better using the tkinter root.after function.  When I run the following in IDLE

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import perf_counter as timer

root = tk.Tk()
n = 1000
def tick():
    global n
    if n:
        #print(n)
        root.after(1, tick)
        n -= 1
    else:
        print(timer() - start)
        root.quit()

root.after(1, tick)
start = timer()
root.mainloop()
```

the output is repeatably just under 1.05 seconds, very close to the target 1.00.  If I uncomment the tick print statement, the time is 4.2 seconds.  In IDLE, the print goes through a socket to a separate process, which is a bit slow.  Running in Windows Command Prompt, the 1000 print time is 1.3 seconds.  I expect that this is about what you would get outputting to a serial post as long as the recipient can keep up with the flow.

EDIT One could do something similar with the relatively new `asyncio` module, and with a bit more effort, even use the newer `async for` syntax.  But I do not have the needed knowledge memorized.

Comment: Very interesting solution. I ran it and it worked. Since my application already has tkinter applied, I need to figure out how to do after for a specific frame that contains the button to trigger this function. Thanks so much!

Comment: I believe you can simply omit the module-level root.after call and make `tick` the button command.  Or call it from the button command function after doing setup.

Comment: I ran into the same problem again even with tk after() function. It only runs well when Chrome is on. very weird.

Comment: I just found out another interesting thing that this only happens on Windows machine. I have tried it on my Mac and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general sleep functions in POSIX, and presumably Windows as well, are guaranteed to sleep for at least the duration specified (unless interrupted earlier by a signal), but they may sleep arbitrarily long after the specified duration depending on when the OS thread scheduler decides to wake the thread.

You could try running your program with a realtime scheduling policy, e.g. in case you're using Linux see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_setscheduler and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html .